# Path file pics not added to database

Tags: gallery

I have 2 Problem:
1- Picture Path "C:\pic\1.jpg" not added
2- Also i want make a copy of 1.jpg to mysite/img

```
<Form action="addgallery.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_upload" />
<input type="submit" name="smbit" value="Save" /></Form>

<?php require_once('db.php');
if($_POST['smbit']){
     $name=basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
     $t_name=$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
     $dir='img';
     if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
     {
            if(mysql_query("insert into pics (pid,pfile) values (' ','$_FILES[pfile]')"))

         echo 'File Upload Sucessfully';
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'Upload Failed!';
     }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $filep="img/".$_FILES["file_upload"]["name"];
>     copy($_FILES["pfile"]["tmp_name"],$filep); mysql_query("INSERT INTO
>   pics(pid,pfile) VALUES(' ','$filep')",$cn);